# David Persson's Media Plugin in Cakephp 2.0.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using the Media plugin by David Persson for CakePHP (https://github.com/davidpersson/media). I used Cakephp 2.0.x and I put the media folder into the plugin. My problem is, an Error message appears and it tells that there is a missing plugin.

```
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the Media plugin

Error: Make sure your plugin Media is in the app\Plugin directory and was loaded

<?php
CakePlugin::load('Media');


Loading all plugins: If you wish to load all plugins at once, use the following line in your app\Config\bootstrap.php file

CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

By the way, I download the zip from the github page davidpersson (which was made using 1.3.x) and I am trying to use it in 2.0.x version. I also change the class name and instead of using var (from 1.3.x) i already added public instead of var for the controllers and models.  What considerations do I need in order to use this plugin in Cakephp 2.0.x? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions Cake tells you and loaded the plugin in bootstrap.php? If not do so.

Read this page http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

There is everything you need to know about how to update 1.3 code to 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

It does not currently support 2.0 (see this ticket: https://github.com/davidpersson/media/issues/66). Within that ticket, however, is a link to someone's fork that has been upgraded to 2.0.

Comment: i forgot to say thanks. maybe i'll try this once I have a spare time.

Comment: Okay, you should probably accept this as the answer then as well so others know why the media plugin doesn't support 2.x. Also, I have it working on a 2.1, fyi.